# How to fix client error in twillio API SMS Verification in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, api, web-services, one-time-password

I am making web service for mobile app developer.I want to make OTP in laravel. I am trying to do this with twillio trial sms. Doing this with the help of this link.

[SMS VERFICATION LINK WHICH I FOLLOWED](https://medium.com/@zilayhuda/sms-verification-using-twilio-api-on-laravel-5-6-23493cdfe12f)

[image]

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Twilio\Jwt\ClientToken;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use phpseclib\Crypt\Random;

class SmsController extends Controller
{
  protected $code, $smsVerification;

  function __construct()
  {
    $this->smsVerification = new \App\SmsVerification();
  }

  public function store (Request $request)
  {
    $code = rand(1000,9999); // Generate Random Code
    $request['code'] = $code; // Add code in request body.
    $this->smsVerification->store($request); //call store method of model
    return $this->sendSms($request); // send and return its response
  }
  public function sendSms($request)
  {
     $accountSid = config('app.twilio')['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'];
     $authToken = config('app.twilio')['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'];
    try
     {
     $client = new Client(['auth' => [$accountSid, $authToken]]);
     $result = $client->post("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$accountSid/Messages.json",
     ['form_params' => [
     'Body' => 'CODE: '. $request->code, //set message body
     'To' => $request->contact_number,
     'From' => '+12056193751' //we get this number from twilio
     ]]);
     return $result;
     }
     catch (Exception $e)
     {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? Check the URL to which you send your request.

Comment: Error is that. Value is empty in $accountSid. config('app.twilio')['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']) it is not getting value from config/app.php

Answer (score 1):

The URL you trying is invalid. You are missing the `AccountSid` in the URL. The format should be `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json`

Code issue in your case. Check if you set value for `config('app.twilio')['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']`, seems like the value is empty and your code is not appending the Twilio account id in the POST URL and throwing a 404.

Read more at their [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource)

Comment: So in my case this is the correct way  https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{$accountSid}/Messages.json

Comment: I have updated the answer, please see the updated answer.

Comment: `$result = $client->post('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json',` this line is incorrect. should be `$result = $client->post("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$accountSid/Messages.json"`

Comment: update your code with the current version in the question.

Comment: before the try statement run `dd(config('app.twilio')['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']);` and  see if you are getting the account sid as expected.

Comment: No result. again getting error on postman. Sfdump = window.Sfdump this error

Comment: what is the value? Seems like you didn't set the values. Did you set in `config/app.php` `'twilio' => [
    'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'  => env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'),
    'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID' => env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
],` and set the `.env` file `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` ?

Comment: never seen the notation `config('app.twilio')['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']` sure it shouldn´t be `config('app.twilio.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')` ?

Comment: YEs i have added values in .env and app.php file

Comment: Seems like Twilio send you a clear message now, now your code is correct and the request is reaching Twilio, the issue is with the credentials. Double-check your `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` and `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` values and make sure that is exactly as same as in your Twilio dashboard.

Comment: Please edit your previous message and remove your `SID` values from it, its never a good idea to post this publically.